# Is this sentence grammatically correct? “If I never asked you, you wouldn’t have told me right?”

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> If I never asked you, you wouldn’t have told me right?

Answer (score 2):

At least this should be:

> If I never asked you, you wouldn’t have told me, right?

Here "right" makes this a question, by asking for confirmation,as in "that's what I ought to do, right?"

But i think this would be significantly better if recast as:

> If I **had** never asked you, you wouldn’t have told me, right?

This puts it clearly into an unreal past. The speaker **did** ask, and was told, but is now speculating on what **would** have happened had things been done differently.